# ExpressJs, why is request body empty?

Tags: javascript, express

I use ExpressJs to create a simple app, receiving a post request (also allow handling form submission).

My index.js file:

```
require ('./models/db');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const hotelController = require('./controllers/hotelController'); 

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, public, 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(30001, () => console.log("listen on 30001"))

app.use('/hotel', hotelController);
```

Below is the controller file, nothing special, just accepting a POST request, however, when I tried logging out the request, I just see empty bracket `{}`, and the code after that breaks. The body of the request is empty, regardless posting from a form or using postman

```
const express = require ('express');
var router = express.Router(); 
const blagoose = require ('mongoose'); 
const Hotel = blagoose.model('Hotel'); 



router.post('/',(req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        //if (req.body._id === "")
            insertRecord(req,res); 
       // else
            //updateRecord(req,res);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("some error just happen " + error.message)
        
        
        }
        

   })

//some more code
module.exports = router;
```

**Edit 1:**
Postman screenshot:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
So, after ozgur's tip on checking Postman header (changing Content-Type to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**), the Postman request works (it has a good body). However, I tried to handle from the form, it becomes empty again. Here's the code in my index.html file (I know it's messy when javascript and html are in the same file, bear with me on that).

```
<form  name="formInfo"  autocomplete="off" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputOwnerName">Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOwnerName" placeholder="Some name" value="Test Name" >
    
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn btn-yellow" style="width: 200px;">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>   

<script> 
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("formInfo");
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

    // var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"); 
    var oData = new FormData(form);
    
    var ownerName = document.getElementById("inputOwnerName").value;
    alert(ownerName);

    oData.append("inputOwnerName", ownerName);

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "/hotel", true);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            // oOutput.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
        } else {
            // oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.<br \/>";
        }
    };

    oReq.send(oData);
    ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Presumably because none of your body parsers match the data format you are posting, but we don't know what that is. It might help if you provided the HTML of the form.

Comment: Do you post to "/hotel" in postman? Can you send a screenshot from your postman screen?

Comment: As a side note, you do not to use body-parser with Express 4.16+ . Here are release notes https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0 - > `Add express.json and express.urlencoded to parse bodies`

Comment: @ozgur I've updated my question with a screenshot, tks

Comment: @Quentin trying via Postman doesn't work. Mostly I want to get it done via Postman, I've updated my Postman screenshot.

Comment: @TaxiNoiBaiHaNoi I added some code below which may fix your issue. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please change your code and instead of this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Just use this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

And in Postman, use this content type: `"application/json"` and try submitting with Raw data

[image]

**EDIT: my default post headers for json data**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's still the same, shows an empty body :(

Comment: Your postman request headers may be missing some of the fields. Maybe you disabled these. I added my default headers in the screenshot above so, you can compare with yours

Comment: Yay! it works now with application/json. How do I change it back form data? Anyway I'm playing around with it now, awesome help

Comment: I’m happy to help

Comment: seems like I'm having problems with sending from the form, updated my question (Edit2). Can you help, tks?

Comment: Try this code app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

Comment: Add that just after or before app.use(express.json()); line

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work, any other possibility?

Comment: @TaxiNoiBaiHaNoi I'm out of ideas sorry

Answer (score -2):

First swap these two lines with each other

```
app.listen(30001, () => console.log("listen on 30001"))

app.use('/hotel', hotelController);
```

Next the reason that its empty is that controller is not defined correctly i.e. where did you `export` the `router` object from controller? Try this:

```
---
module.exports = router
```

Comment: Yes, I did export router in my code, but I just didn't paste it in. Just done now, please see updated code, thanks. I try swapping the line app.listen() like you said, no change.

Comment: You should always put complete code when asking... How should I know that you are not doing anything wrong if you don't put your complete setup? Your ir-responsibility just cost me downvotes.